# HP Proliant ML350 G6 Smart Error Test

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, smart

I have a ML350 G6 with two array controllers : P410 and P410i. I have updated all possibile firmware on this server. I have 5 x Seagate Savvio 10K SAS drives. I am testing the drives with HP Insight Diagnostics. I put two drives on one array, 3 on the other.

Result : all 5 drives fail the Smart Error test, but suceeeds the

In the error log, I can see that "an internal software error has occured". Now I really doubt that my five drives might crash soon, so how come these 5 errors ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are these HP supplied drives? If so have you updated the microcode/firmware on the drives themselves?

Comment: Also which OS is installed and what is the firmware versions on the two controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the HP Insight Diagnostics in this case... You're clearly using non-HP disks in the server. While the disks would function fine, don't expect HP's specific diagnostics tool to check the devices cleanly.

Why are you running diagnostics if you don't suspect a problem?

Boot into your real OS and make sure you install the [HP Management drivers for the system](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3884316&lang=en&lang=en&cc=us&cc=us&ac.admitted=1360753835186.876444892.492883150). That is the proper way to monitor your drives while in service.

You can install the `hpacucli` utility in order to check the status of the RAID volumes and disks.